# How to retrieve tuples from list of string tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
a=['(10,13)', '(23,45)', '(56,78)']
```

Here each item in list `a` is a string

I want an other list like this:

```
b=[(10,13),(23,45),(56,78)]
```

where each item is a tuple and each element in each tuple is an integer.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> a = ['(10,13)', '(23,45)', '(56,78)']
>>> b = [literal_eval(x) for x in a]
>>> b
[(10, 13), (23, 45), (56, 78)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> a = ['(10,13)', '(23,45)', '(56,78)']
>>> b = [literal_eval(s) for s in a]
>>> b
[(10, 13), (23, 45), (56, 78)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use map:

```
from ast import literal_eval
a=['(10,13)', '(23,45)', '(56,78)']
b=map(literal_eval,a)  #[(10, 13), (23, 45), (56, 78)]
```